# I'm having trouble with my extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I've been working on a small Google Chrome extension that replaces some words with other words, but when I try to load the extension, Google tells me that there is a "Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 12, column: 2, Unexpected data after root element." error, and I cannot fix it. Thanks!

```
   //credit goes to /u/adamrsb48

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Random Plugins",
  "version": "0.1"
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["plugins.js"]
    }
]


}
```

Comment: You are missing a `,` between the closing brace of the `background` object and the `"content_scripts"` key, also between the value `"0.1"` and the key: `"background"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing two commas; after "version": "0.1" and after "background": {...}

Try this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Random Plugins",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "plugins.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `,` some where
i fixed it for you

```js
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Random Plugins",
 "version": "0.1",
 "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
 },
 "content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "js": ["plugins.js"]
 }]


}
```

you can use [this](http://jsonlint.com/) to check valid JSON